# .NET Framework の上で動作するアプリケーションのサポートOSの範囲およびテストについて

Tags: c#, windows, .net

.NET Framework上で動作するC#アプリケーションの動作環境として
Windows Server 2016とWindows Server 2019を両方サポートしたいと考えております。

.NET Frameworkは、4.6.2でコンパイルします。（VisualStudioでターゲットフレームワークを4.6.2に設定する。）
Windows Server 2016のデフォルト.NET Framework は、4.6.2
Windows Server 2019のデフォルト.NET Framework は、4.7.2

この場合、両方のOSで全てのテストを実施するのが望ましいと思いますが、
.NET Frameworkの互換性が保たれていればどちらかのOSで動作確認を実施すれば、
問題ないと考えて差し支えないでしょうか？

ノウハウや公式の記事等分かりましたら教えて頂きたく、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「4.6.2でコンパイルする」とは、ターゲットフレームワークを4.6.2にするという意味ですね？念のため。

Comment: ご認識の通り、ターゲットフレームワークを4.6.2という意味です。